# Save multiple forms in one view

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have the following relational models:

```
class Anuncio(models.Model):
    anunciante = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name=_("anunciante"), on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    titulo = models.CharField(_("titulo del anuncio"), max_length=50)

class Producto(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(_("nombre del producto"), max_length=50)
    anuncio = models.ForeignKey(Anuncio, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='products', blank=True, null=True)

class Imagen(models.Model):
    producto = models.ForeignKey(Producto, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='imagen', blank=True, null=True)
    imagen = models.ImageField(upload_to='marketplace/')
```

I have a form, that allows adding an instance of all of three models with the proper relations. This works okay, but I'm trying to add a feature that adds additional `Producto` and `Imagen` instances to the same `Anuncio`. I'm rendering the additional forms with JavaScript and I get the render OK, but I can't get the data of the additional forms saved. This is the main `Anuncio` create view:

```
def anunciocreateview(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        anuncio_form = AnuncioForm(request.POST or None)
        producto_form = ProductoForm(request.POST or None)
        imagen_form = ImagenForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if all([anuncio_form.is_valid(), producto_form.is_valid(), imagen_form.is_valid()]):
            anuncio = anuncio_form.save(commit=False)
            anuncio.anunciante = request.user
            anuncio.save()
            producto = producto_form.save(commit=False)
            producto.anuncio = anuncio
            producto.save()
            imagen = request.FILES.get('imagen')
            if imagen:
                Imagen.objects.create(producto=producto, imagen=imagen)
            return HttpResponse(status=204, headers={'HX-Trigger' : 'eventsListChanged'})
        else:
            print(anuncio_form.errors)
            print(producto_form.errors)
            print(imagen_form.errors)
    else:
        anuncio_form = AnuncioForm()
        producto_form = ProductoForm()
        imagen_form = ImagenForm()
    context = {
        'anuncio_form' : anuncio_form,
        'producto_form' : producto_form,
        'imagen_form' : imagen_form
    }
    return render(request, 'buyandsell/formulario.html', context)
```

And this is the view regarding the additional `Producto` and `Imagen` only forms:

```
def create_product(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        producto_form = ProductoForm(request.POST or None)
        imagen_form = ImagenForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if all([producto_form.is_valid(), imagen_form.is_valid()]):
            producto = producto_form.save()
            imagen = request.FILES.get('imagen')
            if imagen:
                Imagen.objects.create(producto=producto, imagen=imagen)
            return HttpResponse("Product added.")
    else:
        producto_form = ProductoForm()
        imagen_form = ImagenForm()
    context = {
        'producto_form' : producto_form,
        'imagen_form' : imagen_form
    }
    return render(request, 'buyandsell/partials/producto-form.html', context)
```

The first view saves the data okay, but the additional forms don't get saved. I tried also looking at formsets, but I haven't figured out neither how could I accomplish such task.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `formset` for that.
For further information, you can check out Django's documentation on formsets here:
[Formsets in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/formsets/)